# Files stored in Android/data/com.example.com/files/temp/3452345.mp3 rather than /Download with correct file name

Tags: android

I am brand new, just opened Android Studio for the first time a couple months ago. I've managed to learn enough to compile an already coded native Android App.

In the app it allows you to setup a php admin backend which then feeds the mp3 audio files content to the Android app. Whenever I save a file using the app, it saves in /Android/data/app.example.com/files/temp directory, and saves the file under some random numerical name such as 234234234.mp3.

Here is the code that I think is responsible, but I have no idea what to do.

```
    public Boolean checkDownload(String id) {
        File root = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("").getAbsolutePath() + "/temp");

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DOWNLOAD_SONG, columns_download_song, TAG_SID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
        boolean isDownloaded;
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String filename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TAG_TEMP_NAME));
            File file = new File(root, filename + ".mp3");
            isDownloaded = file.exists();
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            isDownloaded = false;
        }
        return isDownloaded;
    }
```

My ultimate goal is to get it to download the files to the phone's /Download directory with the correct file name.

[image]

The odd thing is in the app itself on my Android phone, there is a Downloads link in the side menu, and when I press it, the actual song shows as downloaded with the correct name.

Comment: The code you pasted checks if a certain file is in getExternalFilesDir(). It does download nothing. So it is irrelevant if you want to change something to download to Download folder instead

Comment: Hi Sir @halfer, I clicked the blackapps link and it showed me a profile, then I seen the Accessing external storage, which I presume is what I need to do. I believe I understand it specifying the items I need to add to the manifest; however, may you suggest any particular area? Perhaps add above this particular area, but not below this? I don't want to bother anyone further, and I won't be submitting the app to Google. Thank you for your initial reply and in advance if you so-choose to answer again.

Comment: I wonder if you intended your message to be a reply to @blackapps. I merely edited the question on this page - I don't have any Android programming experience.